# Sub-query within a view optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization

I have a view that reads from two tables `Call` and `Caller`, both those tables are parallel in that they are keyed on the same ID (i.e. to get the Caller information for a Call, you join on Call.id = Caller.id).  I have a view that spans these two tables to return composite information about any particular call or set of calls.

But I have a subquery in that view that is used to determine if the caller has been called back or not (defined as there exists another call for the same phone number made after this call with a status of completed).  This subquery is making the view extremely slow to query but I'm not sure what would be a better way to include this information.  Below are the relevant DDLs, thoughts?

Edit: Would this query be fine with some indexes added or would there be a more efficient way to structure the query itself?

```
CREATE TABLE [CALL]
(
    ID VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY, --this is a legacy system, I know varchar(64) isn't an efficient primary key
    CALLDATE DATETIME,
    STATUS BIT --1 = Complete, 0 = Incomplete
)

CREATE TABLE [CALLER]
(
    ID VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY,
    PHONENUMBER VARCHAR(10),
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(50),
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE VIEW [CALLVIEW] AS
SELECT
    CALL.ID AS CALLID,
    CALL.CALLDATE AS CALLDATE,
    CALL.STATUS AS CALLSTATUS,
    CALLER.PHONENUMBER AS PHONENUMBER,
    CALLER.FIRSTNAME AS FIRSTNAME,
    CALLER.LASTNAME AS LASTNAME,
    CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1
                           FROM [CALL] CALL2
                           INNER JOIN [CALLER] CALLER2 ON CALL2.ID = CALLER2.ID
                           WHERE CALLER2.PHONENUMBER = CALLER.PHONENUMBER
                           AND CALL2.CALLDATE > CALL.CALLDATE
                           AND CALL2.STATUS = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS CALLEDBACK
FROM
    [CALL]
    INNER JOIN [CALLER] ON [CALL].ID = [CALLER].ID
```

Edit:  From the execution plan I notice that by far the most expensive components of the query are the following:

Clustered Index Seek

Predicate:       CALL2.CALLDATE > CALL.CALLDATE AND CALL2.STATUS = 1

Object:          [CALL].[PK_CALL] CALL2 (so it's using the primary key index)

Output List:     [CALL].CALLDATE, [CALL].STATUS

Seek Predicates: [CALL].id = Scalar Operator([CALLER].id)

Index Seek

Object:          [CALLER].[IX_PHONENUMBER] CALLER2 (so it's using the proper index but still expensive?)

Output List:     [CALLER].ID

Seek Predicates: [CALLER].PHONENUMBER = Scalar Operator([CALLER].PHONENUMBER)

Comment: Having "TOP 1" in your EXISTS() clause is useless and can only hurt performance.

Comment: Also have you looked at the actual execution plan? I'd be surprised if it didn't recommend some indexes that would help the subquery...

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks, I didn't have it there before but thought it might help performance so I added it, but there isn't any difference in performance with it.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?   Are you familiar with the ROW_NUMBER() OVER() function?

Comment: @TabAlleman I've used it once with a partition before, what would you suggest its use is here?

Comment: If the rowNumber (or maybe Rank would be better considering your existing logic) over each PhoneNumber, Ordered by CallDate DESC isn't 1, then CalledBack = 1, else 0.  Can be calculated without a subquery.   Might need a CASE to include the Status=1 part.

Comment: The call that we're looking for in the EXISTS may not exist in the view itself, if the view is queried on status = 0, right?  That's why I felt I had to add the subquery.  Maybe I'm confused.

Comment: yeah the Status might be a problem.  I would have to investigate whether you can filter on a column while doing a RowNumber, and I'm sure you can investigate just as easily as I can, so I'll leave it at that.  But that was my train of thought.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've addded some detail to my question about the execution plan.

Comment: Can you post the Execution Plan?  That would make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to use the **Database Engine Tuning Advisor**, it'll tell you if you need to create some indexes.

Anyway, here's what I'd do:

- Verify that you actually have a CLUSTERED Index on CALL.ID and on CALLER.ID (being a legacy system,  maybe you have the PK but someone dropped the index)
- Create NON CLUSTERED Index on:

  - CALLER.PHONENUMBER
  - CALL.CALLDATE
  - CALL.STATUS
- Reorganize/Rebuild Indexes
- Update Statistics

Comment: I have verified that I have both clustered PK indexes.  There is no CALL.PHONENUMBER, only CALLER.PHONENUMBER which already has a nonclustered index on it.  I tried making a nonclustered index yesterday spanning CALL.CALLDATE and CALL.STATUS but that didn't seem to help.  I'll try reorganizing the indexes.

Comment: Can you take a look at the execution plan and see if the indexes are correct.

Comment: Well, it's kinda hard to understand it in this way. Try to use the "Database Engine Tuning Advisor", it'll tell you if you need to create some indexes. Anyway, are you sure that this view doesn't have acceptable performance? What's its execution time?

Comment: Thanks this tuning advisor is very helpful.  And queries on the view were taking 20+ seconds which was not acceptable.  The advisor told me to add an index on CALLER.ID + CALLER.PHONENUMBER and another one on CALL.ID + CALL.STATUS + CALL.CALLDATE.